# How to identify branch name through the build id in yaml script or task whatever?

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

Have validate thorough the different ways

```
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  displayName: 'Download artifact'
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: '$(resources.pipeline.DfmPublish.projectID)'
    definition: '$(resources.pipeline.DfmPublish.pipelineID)'
    ${{ if eq(parameters.artifactBuildId, 'latestFromBranch') }}:
      buildVersionToDownload: 'latestFromBranch'
      branchName: 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.artifactBranch }}'
    ${{ if ne(parameters.artifactBuildId, 'latestFromBranch') }}:
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      runId: '${{ parameters.artifactBuildId }}'
      buildId: '$(resources.pipeline.DfmPublish.runID)'
      branchName: 'refs/heads/${{ parameters.artifactBranch }}'
    targetPath:  '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\aritfactname
```

and also run some script but it will run only for source branch

ex -
there are 3 branches :

**branch A** is build branch and **branch B** is where we using build artifact .

If we use build id form **branch C** pipeline will select latest build from **'branch A'**  and if build Id from **'branch A'** so no need to check latest branch from the **branch A**.

If we use build id form **branch C** pipeline will select latest build from **'branch A'**  and if build Id from **'branch A'** so no need to check latest branch from the **branch A**.